# No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby

Tags: java, database, spring, maven, derby

I am creating simple HelloWorld web application. I want to use local derby db.

my pom:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.14.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

And connection service class MyDB, I want just get text from table and show:

```
public void connecToDerby() throws SQLException{

        String dbUrl = "jdbc:derby:D:\\Projects\\JavaWebApplication\\FirstMavenProject; create=true";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);

    }

    public void initDb() throws SQLException {
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate("Create table welcometext(id int primary key, text varchar(100))");

        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT into welcometext values (1, 'Hello Java World')");
        statement.close();
    }
```

but I got Exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:D:\Projects\JavaWebApplication\FirstMavenProject; create=true
```

How to solve it? Is it right to use local derby? I am working on Intelij IDEA.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you are not loading the driver class. Please use one of the following based on your need

- Running Derby in Network Mode   then use
  `Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");`
- Running derby
  in Embedded Mode 
  `Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");`

before getting a connection from `DriverManager`.

Comment: Can you please put the updated code in question and also is it still the same exception coming?

Comment: Are you running derby in Network Mode or Embedded Mode ?

Comment: in Embedded Mode

Answer (score 0):

My code is here, It is works. maybe you lose `Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER_NAME);`

```
    private static final String JDBC_DRIVER_NAME = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
    private static final String NACOS_HOME = "D:\\nacos";
    private static final String DERBY_BASE_DIR = "data" + File.separator + "derby-data";
    private static final String USER_NAME = "nacos";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "nacos";

    static Connection conn = null;

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        if (conn==null){
            try {
                Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER_NAME);
                String url = "jdbc:derby:" + NACOS_HOME + File.separator + DERBY_BASE_DIR + ";create=true";
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, USER_NAME, PASSWORD);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return conn;
    }
```